# Choose a specific value from duplicate values with expressions in QGIS

Tags: duplicates, expression, qgis

I have a layer vectors with 2 columns, the first one is "NAME" and second one is "DATE". However the name columns has lot of duplicate values so I'm try to creating a expression to choose the NAME with has the most recent DATE. Can anyone could help me?

Thanks in advance!

So far I found out how to identify the duplicate values with the expresssion: COUNT(1,  "NAME" )>1.

I also tried this expression, but I got sintax error:
with_variable('max_date', maximum("DATE"),
array_first(
array_agg($id, filter:=("NAME" IN array_agg("NAME", group_by:="NAME") AND "DATE" = @max_date))
)
)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) QGIS processing algorithm.

- Set in the **Group by expression** parameter the field named "NAME"
- And in the aggregation table set just one row with the field "DATE" and use the aggregation function "maximum". Fill the oder columns with the correct values. Then run the algorithm.